# Pop Ups in Browser - Possible Viruses?

Tags: browser, samsung, popup

Since moving to Japan, the chrome web browser on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3) has been acting strangely.  Sometimes it will happen when I switch to a new article on a news mobile website, or even if I click a link on facebook.  What happens is that a popup comes up that takes up the whole screen that claims my phone has a virus and I should download something to get rid of it.  I'm not an idiot, so I never click those popups and close the page immediately.  My question is that I'm wondering if I may already have a virus on my phone, and that's why I'm getting these pop ups all of the sudden.  Is there a good way to check for viruses on phones?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a malware app. Have you tried one of those ad scanners ([Addons Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.denper.addonsdetector), [AppBrain Ad Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector), [Lookout Ad Network Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.lookout.addetector)) to find possible candidates? Any app you lately installed (possibly side-loaded) that could match?

Answer (score 0):

You can block pop ups for all sites in the chrome setting however I still get those spammy pop ups even after blocking pop ups for all sites in chrome beta.. All those pop ups you get saying that" your device has virus" or" your device is running slow" are absolutely spam. Those have no relation with your device. Their main motto is to mislead audience and make them install malicious apps that can compromise the security of device..But if you need some good security you can find plenty of them on the play store. You can go for 360mobile security which has a great detection rate and is free to download. Or you can go for Lookout that has a good anti-theft feature that is also free.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you there is no virus in your device. Those pop-ups will just lead you to any application and games sites, dating sites, etc. Internal pop-blocker of Chrome won't help you in this case. I would advice normal browsers like UC Browser mini & Opera mini to get rid of the pop-ups. Try them and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, Suyash Barve. I hadn't thought of that possibility.

Good answer, MANI, however this is abnormal under any of the top dozen browsers. Annnnd, antivirus apps just give you a false sense of security.

Next time that happens, I'd use the shellcode below to investigate these four places. Get the android terminal app.

```
shell@android:/data/data/com.browser.application # ls
cache
databases
files
lib
```

Maybe not lib....

Try this first:
https://adblockplus.org/android-faq

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact problem. It went from my phone to my PC to my laptop. Reset my phone thrice to get rid of it but the pop ups would start again immediately after reset. I finally figured out that the problem was on my WiFi. My computer that had been hooked up to the wifi had a network virus and had infected everything that was connected to it. Disconnect everything from your wifi. Then connect one thing at a time as you download Quickheal and run their malware program. Once you've done it for the computer/laptop, the phone should be fine after a reset.

Comment: This does not sound very plausible.